# Ruby : call the assign method in another class

Tags: ruby, oop

I do this :

```
class Money

attr_reader :value

def initialize(init_amount = 0)
    self.value = init_amount
end

def value=(new_amount)
    if new_amount >= 0
        @value = new_amount
    else
        puts "ERROR: value can't be less than 0."
    end
end

def to_s
    ("%.2f" % @value).split(".").join(",")
end
end
```

And in another class, I call my object :

```
load 'Money.rb'

class Transaction

attr_reader :amount

def initialize(init_amount)
    @amount = Money.new(init_amount)
end

def amount=(new_amount)
    @amount = new_amount # Why it doesn't work??
    # Why I need to do this ?
    # @amount.value=(new_amount)
end

end
```

Why @amount = new_amount doesn't call the method value=() of Money class?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What you want is to be able to override the assignment operator. You can't do that in Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@amount` is initialized to an instance of `Money`.

I'm assuming that `new_amount` is a double like `13.33`. Then, of course, what you're doing is taking `@amount` and simply setting it to `13.33`. So, now, you've overwritten your instance of `Money` and replaced it with `13.33`.

Your `value=` is a setter method. That is what you use to set a particular attribute of an Object from outside its implementation. It is an API that you let the world access to change the value of money. So, in Transaction, you need to use this API you made to change value.

So, of course, if you want to change the value of your `Money` instance, you're going to have to do `@amount.value = new_amount`.

Edit:

You will never be able to do to `@amount = new_amount` and expect it to set the `value` of your Money instance. To achieve this, you would have to override the assignment operator in Ruby and that isn't possible.

Comment: O yes of course, @amount is an object! Sorry, I'm too tired maybe..  Thanks a lot for your help and your explications !!!